# Is it still possible to integrate Google Sign-In within a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-signin, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been attempting to follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/chrome-extension) to integrate Google Sign-In within my chrome extension, but I kept getting an error saying that,

````
Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0/firebase.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'```."
````

I then tried to include,

```
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' https://securetoken.googleapis.com;"
}
```

in my manifest as stated in the aforementioned guide, but then I got the error,

```
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.
```

I then removed the content security policy and tried to include the `firebase.js` file in my extension directly, but then now I get an error saying,

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb944385' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

I don't think I'm doing the content security policy incorrectly, so my question is if it's still possible to integrate Google Sign-In within a Chrome Extension. My guess would be no and that it's related to how Manifest V3 will not [execute remote code anymore](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code), but I just wanted to double check to make sure that I wasn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: Apparently it's broken, see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/xQmZLc8cu6Q/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! Someone in that thread actually included [boilerplate code](https://github.com/RasikaWarade/chrome-extension-mv3-firebase-boilerplate) for a successful integration of Google Sign-In which is helping me understand how everything works.